# Selling Corrupt quality of honey with allegation...

Tags: percentages, ratio

I have a problem that uses Allegation concept, I tried it I would like to know If I am Correct..?

> A Honey seller gets pure honey($1$ Litre ) for $100$  and  a sweet oil for $20$ he shall mix honey and sweet oil and sell the mixture at same Cost price with gain $40$ %. In what ratio does he mix ?

Using allegations concept I calculated the solution and obtained $5:9$.

Some one answer me.

all transactions at ideal currency for your convenience...;-)

Comment: what do you mean by "at the same cost price"? It's a bit counter-intuitive to say selling at cost price will lead to a gain

Comment: @LiuGang; not if one sell corrupt honey at the same cost price of genuine honey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer:  Your answer is correct.  Here are the steps below

He buys 1 litre of pure honey for $100.  Sweet oil costs $20 per litre. Let us assume that he mixes "x" litre of sweet oil with honey.  The total volume is 1+x.

Cost price $= 100*1 + 20*x$

Revenue $= (1+x)*100$

Percentage gain $= 0.4$

Gain $= (1+x)*100 - (100+20x) = 80x$

Percentage gain $= \frac{80x}{100+20x} = 0.4$

Solve for x and you will get 5/9.

So for 1 liter of honey he  mixes 5/9 litre of sweet oil to realize 40% profit percentage